# PHP - Find/Replace Text in RTF/txt files

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm running into an issue with finding specific text and replacing it with alternative text.
I'm testing my code below with `.rtf` and `.txt` files only.  I'm also ensuring the files are writable, from within my server.

It's a hit and miss situation, and I'm curious if my code is wrong, or if this is just weirdness of opening and manipulating files.

```
<?php

$filelocation = '/tmp/demo.txt';
$firstname = 'John';
$lastname = 'Smith';

$output = file_get_contents($filelocation);
$output = str_replace('[[FIRSTNAME]]', $firstname, $output);
$output = str_replace('[[LASTNAME]]', $lastname, $output);
$output = str_replace('[[TODAY]]', date('F j, Y'), $output);

// rewrite file
file_put_contents($filelocation, $output);

?>
```

So, inside the `demo.txt` file I have about a full page of text with [[FIRSTNAME]], [[LASTNAME]], and [[TODAY]] scattered around.

It's hit and miss with the find/replace.  So far, [[TODAY]] is always replaced correctly, while the names aren't.

Has anyone had this same issue?

(on a side note, I've checked error logs and so far no PHP warning/error is returned from opening the file, nor writing it)

Comment: can you put some of text inside demo.txt , so we can have idea what is wrong

Comment: Good point, I'll try that....

Comment: Weird - tried your code with a simple text file and it works precisely as expected. Not sure what's happening to your stuff. Post up demo file?

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight. You want to replace `[[FIRSTNAME]]` with `John` and `[[LASTNAME]]` with `Smith`?

Comment: Exactly, it's a find and replace scenario.

Comment: Another question. Is it exactly the string `[[FIRSTNAME]]` or `[[John]]`, `[[Robert]]` etc. as first names? I ask this because the tests I made while playing around with it, came up positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without seeing the contents of demo.txt. My first guess is that it might be a problem with using brackets for your pointers. I would try changing to something not used by RTF like percent signs or an asterisk. ex: %%FIRSTNAME%%, **FIRSTNAME** (this is assuming of course that you have control of the contents of demo.txt.)

Comment: It appears it's really an `.rtf` issue.  I've tested it over with `.txt` and it's working fine there. Perhaps there are weird invisible formatting additives produced by Microsoft Word.

Comment: Yes, RTF adds all types of formatting characters. Please up vote or mark as the answer if my response was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you're right. I needed to vote up.  I used your idea to try different Pre/Post tagging parameters.  Also, I removed all formatting from the `.rtf` and seems that was a solution.  Hurray for Rich Text, kinda.

Comment: I've ran into this a few times. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue too. It seems like Microsoft Word inserts formatting codes in the tags. I have made a blog post about how to get around this on my technical blog.

http://tech.humlesite.eu/2017/01/13/using-regular-expression-to-merge-database-content-into-rich-text-format-template-documents/

The PHP example is shown here:

```
<?php 

$file = file_get_contents('mergedoc.rtf');

// To temporary get rid of the escape characters...
$mergetext = str_replace("\\", "€€", $file); 

// New seven part regex with default value detection
$regex2 = '/<<((?:€€[a-z0-9]*|\}|\{|\s)*)([a-z0-9.\-\+_æøåÆØÅA-Z]*)((?:€€[a-z0-9]*|\}|\{|\s)*)([a-z0-9.\-\+_æøåÆØÅA-Z]*)((?:€€[a-z0-9]*|\}|\{|\s)*)(?:\s*:(.*?)\s*)?((?:€€[a-z0-9]*|\}|\{|\s)*)>>/';

// Find all the matches in it....
preg_match_all($regex2,$mergetext, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// Lets see the result
var_dump($out); 

foreach ($out as $match) {
    $whole_tag = $match[0]; // The part we actually replace. 
    $start = $match[1]; // The start formatting that has been injected in our tag, if any
    $tag = $match[2]; // The tag word itself. 
    if (($match[4].$match[6]) != "") { //some sec-part tag or default value?
        $end = $match[5]; // The end formatting that might be inserted. 
        if ($end == "") {
            $end = $match[7]; // No end in 5, we try 7. 
        }
    } else {
        $end = $match[3]; // No second tag or default value, we find end in match-3 
    }

    $secPartTag = $match[4]; // Do we have inserted some formatting inside the tag word too ? 
    if ($secPartTag != "") {
        $tag .= $secPartTag; // Put it together with the tag word. 
    }
    $default_value = $match[6]; 

    // Simple selection of what we do with the tag. 
    switch ($tag) {
        case 'COMPANY_NAME': 
            $txt = "MY MERGE COMPANY EXAMPLE LTD"; 
            break; 
        case 'SOMEOTHERTAG':
            $txt = "SOME OTHER TEXT XX"; 
            break; 
        case 'THISHASDEFAULT':
            $txt = ""; 
            break; 

        default:
            $txt = "NOTAG"; 
    }
    if ($txt == "") {
        $txt = $default_value; 
    }
    // Create RTF Line breaks in text, if any. 
    $txt = str_replace(chr(10), chr(10)."\\line", $txt); 
    // Do the replace in the file. 
    $mergetext = str_replace($whole_tag, $start.$txt.$end, $mergetext); 
}
// Put back the escape characters. 
$file = str_replace("€€", "\\", $mergetext);
// Save to file. Extention .doc makes it open in Word by default. 
file_put_contents("ResultDoc.doc", $file); 

?>
```